# Azure Resource Manager Deployment Name

Tags: c#, .net, azure, virtual-machine

I want to start an Azure VM attached to a resource group programmatically.

However, the ComputeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.Restart requires a "deploymentName" Parameter, I cannot find in the new portal.
Does anybody have a clue where the deploymentName can be found?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, we have two types of libraries to management our Azure VM, I have install these two libraries in my console application like following screenshoot:
[image]

> where the deploymentName can be found?

[image]
In the second library (Microsoft.**WindowsAzure**.Management.Compute), we can control Azure VM(classic). And the deployment name is the cloud service deployment name. We can find it in Azure portal. Cloud service (classic) -> the specific Cloud service (the same name with your Azure VM) -> settings -> deployment name

If you create a VM under a resource group, please use the first Library (Microsoft.**Azure**.Management.Computer). In this library, we only need to provide the resource group name and Azure VM name, see detailed here:

[image]